# Column selection

Tags: powerbuilder

I am wondering if you could help me out with a query. I am fairly new to PowerBuilder.

I want to know is there any function (in PB 8) to prompt users to select columns they want and show them in the data window similar to `sort()` or `filter()`.

Can you please advise, I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `SyntaxFromSQL`, you can define the SQL sentence dinamically, adding the columns you want. And then, create the datawindow and show results.
You can prompt the columns to the user and construct the SQL Select.

```
string ls_select, ls_dwsyntax, ls_error

ls_select = "Select id, first_name, last_name, address from customer"
ls_dwsyntax = SQLCA.SyntaxFromSQL(ls_select, "Style(Type=grid)", ls_error)

dw_1.Create(ls_dwsyntax, ls_error)
IF ls_error <> '' THEN
   MessageBox("error - Syntax", ls_error)
   RETURN -1
END IF

dw_1.SetTransObject(SQLCA)
dw_1.Retrieve()
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently working on a similar thing. You could dynamicaly set the visibility of a column like this. Lets suppost the columname is `col1` and the datawindow control is `dw_1`

```
string ls_value = "Col1.Visible=0"

ls_value = dw_1.Modify(ls_value)
```

Thats all. For selecting which column the user wants to see I use an another datawindow with the column names and a little checkbox for visibility.

Regards
Gábor